# Declare class property at runtime, in Yii2

Tags: php, reflection, yii2

I have a class that extends from Yii2's `Model` and I need to declare a class public property in the constructor, but I'm hitting a problem.

When I call

```
class Test extends \yii\base\Model {
    public function __constructor() {
        $test = "test_prop";
        $this->{$test} = null; // create $this->test_prop;
    }
}
```

Yii tries to call, from what I understand, the getter method of this property, which of course doesn't exist, so I hit [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/624db0e678767780dd144fcfbbbb040c392e75d8/framework/base/Component.php#L197) exception.

Also, when I actually do `$this->{$test} = null;`, [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/624db0e678767780dd144fcfbbbb040c392e75d8/framework/base/Component.php#L164) method gets called.

My question is: Is there a way to declare a class public property in another way? Maybe some Reflexion trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override getter/setter, e.g. :

```
class Test extends \yii\base\Model
{
    private $_attributes = ['test_prop' => null];

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_attributes))
            return $this->_attributes[$name];

        return parent::__get($name);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_attributes))
            $this->_attributes[$name] = $value;

        else parent::__set($name, $value);
    }
}
```

You could also create a behavior...

Comment: I think `attributes`, internally, uses the same setter and getter that I'm hitting with my way.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Your solution looks exactly like the answer I received from one of Yii's devs :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I [received help](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/pull/13#issuecomment-93694724) from one of Yii's devs. Here is the answer:

```
class Test extends Model {
    private $dynamicFields;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dynamicFields = generate_array_of_dynamic_values();
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->dynamicFields)) {
            $this->dynamicFields[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->dynamicFields)) {
            return $this->dynamicFields[$name];
        } else {
            return parent::__get($name);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I'm using `in_array` instead of `array_key_exists` because the `dynamicFields` array is a plain array, not an associative one.

EDIT: This is actually wrong. See my accepted answer.

Comment: You are wrong about `in_array`, `$dynamicFields` is associative : `$this->dynamicFields[$name] = $value;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set variable in init method.

Like this:

```
public function init() {
  $test = "test_prop";
  $this->{$test} = null; // create $this->test_prop;
  parent::init();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this doesn't fix anything, it just changes the source of the problem.

Comment: Wait, this is model. Did u declare variable $test_prop in class? Like this: public $test_prop